# The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini

Tags: php

I'm using wordpress 3.5.1 and i bought a new theme from themeforest but when i try to upload that theme to my wordpress after uploading it shows the message;

```
"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini".
```

Even i tried to upload theme manually via FTP filezilla, it's not showing anything in my wordpress to activate theme.

I edited my php.ini file; its default size was 64M and I changed it to 256M. Still getting the same problem

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Inside the WorldPress panel, you should see "Appearance" on the side. Click on that.

Then hit "Install Themes", and search for your theme there. That does not require any type of upload limit.

Comment: yeah its the common way to install theme in wordpress ! it shows the same problem .btw thanks for comment.

Comment: Ask your host to up your FTP/bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open php.ini:

> /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

2) Increase File Size:

> upload_max_filesize = 16M

3) Restart:

> sudo service apache2 restart